# Babel not working on OS X?

Tags: unicode, babel, characters, texshop, input-encodings

I'm using a MacBook Air, with OS X, and I have great difficulties in using Latex in my native language (serbian).

If I use the standard babel package in TexShop:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, serbian]{babel}
```

And set keyboard input language to Serbian-latin, when i type letters like

`ž, š, ć`, etc.

I get question marks on the output pdf when I typeset it (PdfTex). As far I understand, OS X uses UTF-8 encoding, so this shouldn't happen, yet it does. Any solutions? :)

P.S. Of course, I can use `\v s` for š and `\' c` for ć, but its very tedious to write like that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should check that your text editor (what is it, by the way?) uses UTF-8.

Comment: do you get errors when you process the document, such as `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�,e not set up for use with LaTeX.
`

Comment: @egreg Yeah, I use TexShop, I figured it's the best one, but I'm open to changing it, don't really like it :) And yes, I've just seen that it uses **'Western (Mac OS Roman)'**  encoding. Should I change it to UTF8? At David, no, I don't get any errors. :)

Comment: @Vidak Yes, change in the preferences to UTF-8.

Comment: @Vidak yes saving in utf-8 is probably the thing to do (although you could use an matching inputenc option instead) I guessed (wrongly) iso-8859-2 and the error I posted was what you get from your input string if you mis-label it as utf8. If the mac encoding gets through without error it's just (un)lucky and producing nonsense/

Comment: @egreg It worked! Thanks!! :) I can't upvote your comment here, but it solved my problem! At David, yes it goes through, very unlucky :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What encoding is used by the operating system is not relevant; the editor you use for typing LaTeX documents might use another.

This is indeed the case for TeXShop, that initially is set up to use MacOSRoman, that is, Latin-1 (or ISO 8859-1).

Check in the Preferences panel, "Source" tab: under "Encoding" you find a drop-down menu, choose Unicode (UTF-8).

Take also the habit of putting at the start of your LaTeX file the line

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

that will prevent encoding problems.

Here's an example document (the text is from [http://sr.wikipedia.org/sr-el/Београд](http://sr.wikipedia.org/sr-el/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4))

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}

\begin{document}

Beograd je glavni i najveći grad Srbije. Jedan je od
najstarijih gradova u Evropi. Prva naselja na teritoriji
Beograda datiraju iz praistorijske Vinče, 4.800 godina pre
nove ere. Sam Beograd su osnovali Kelti u 3. veku pre n. e,
pre nego što je postao rimsko naselje Singidunum. Slovensko
ime „Beligrad“ (slov.~Bjelgrad) prvi put je zabeleženo
878. godine, u čemu je sadržan utisak izgleda tadašnje
tvrđave. Beograd je glavni grad Srbije od 1405. godine i bio
je prestonica raznih južnoslovenskih država od 1918. pa
do 2003, kao i Srbije i Crne Gore od 2003. do 2006.

\end{document}
```

[image]